# How to set up encoding UTF-8 or WINDOWS_CP_1251 in Restful API on node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I created an API with Node.js and Express that returns values in JSON.

I need to encode the values with UTF-8 or Windows_CP_1251 for cyrilic language.

The code:

```
    app.route('/stations')
.get(function(req, res) {
  // omitted
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'content-type', 'charset=utf-8');
  try {
    const query2 = `SELECT Station,Ime FROM aladin_surfex.stations_cells;`;
    con.query(query2, function (err, result2, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      aladinModelStations = result2;
    });
    res.json({aladinModelStations})
  } catch(error){
    console.log("Error query database!!!");

  } 
});

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
});
```

I need to set encoding on the second root endpoint **app.route('/stations')**

[image: For now I cannot read any values.]

Can someone give an example of how to handle the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

you will have to set `content-type` in header. add below block of code before `app.route('/stations')`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   app.setHeader('content-type', 'charset=utf-8');
   return next();
});
```

Comment: The result is the same like a screenshot ;(

Comment: The answer says how to set the header, not to re-encode the text as something else. You are returning JSON, and JSON [should always be UTF-8 or UTF-16 according to the standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1), so other systems, tools or libraries may have big problems dealing with a non-UTF encoding. That said, there's a [1251 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1251).

Comment: Can you give me example how to decode in 1251 with this package ?